# Is there a simple way to specify int value in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I want set Tag property with int value in xaml. But defining int in resources and then reference this resource as binding looks not a perfect way for me. It is easier just to convert string value to int from code.
So, is there some way to easy set int value in xaml?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If not interested in declaring it as resource, you can ***declare it in-line*** somewhat like this:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Tag>
            <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
        </Button.Tag>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is too many letters too.
I need set Tag for several elements like
`Tag="int:0", Tag="int:1"` and so on

Comment: `Tag` property is of type `object`. Even when you want to access it from code behind, you have to do typecast `(int)button.Tag`. Can you tell the use case?

Comment: yes, but (int)button.Tag is more simple than int.Parse((string)button.Tag) :)
ok, as I understand to use string values for this looks is simplest existing way

Comment: Yeah there is no other way in XAML. Or using Resource also seems good to me.

Comment: @Arteny - For either approach, you can make a static extension method that gets the tag property and casts it to int. E.g. `public static int TagAsInt(this YourBaseElementClass e) { return (int)e.Tag; }`.  Then usage is trivial `myElement.TagAsInt()`. If it is easier to define Tag as a string, you just change that method to do the parse, and use it exactly the same.

Comment: That's more like "in-four-lines"

Answer (score 22):

Please try this.

Add namespace  **xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"** in xaml

```
<sys:Int16 x:Key="IntNo">1</sys:Int16> or

<sys:Int32 x:Key="IntNo1" >1</sys:Int32>
```

---

Note : Similarly You can use for **Double value** also.

Comment: For current .NET-runtimes the namespace changed to xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime".

Answer (score 10):

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"


<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="IntValue" >1</sys:Int32>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button x:Name="Button" Tag="{StaticResource IntValue}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Is it simple enough? The above sample will be suitable if you going to use your Value in several places. Otherwise:

```
<Button x:Name="Button" >
        <Button.Tag>
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
        </Button.Tag>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

In XAML 2009 you can simply use the `"x"` prefix, like `x:Boolean`, `x:Decimal` or `x:Int32`.

See [Microsoft - Built-in types for common XAML language primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/types-for-primitives)

**Example:**

This example is from a WinUI 3 application (WinUI 3 XAML is very similar to UWP XAML and mostly similar to WPF XAML)

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Click="MyButton_Click" Content="Print 'Tag' value to console">
           <Button.Tag>
              <x:Int32>42</x:Int32>
           </Button.Tag>
         </Button>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int value = (int) MyButton.Tag;

        Debug.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

You can also spefify a command parameter that accepts an `int` in that way:

```
<Button Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddMinutesCommand}" Content="+ 30 Minutes">
   <Button.CommandParameter>
      <x:Int32>30</x:Int32>
   </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

There seems to be a confusion about the availability of XAML 2009 in various technologies: [Stackoverflow - Can XAML 2009-related markup extensions be used in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414862/can-xaml-2009-related-markup-extensions-be-used-in-wpf)

Honestly, I also do not understand why my working example code can just use `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml` for the `x` namespace
instead of having to specify something like `2009/xaml` here.

Feel free to change this answer, if you can clarify this.

Comment: This one is way more up to date than the other answers. Works on UWP and WinUI3, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `MarkupExtension` to achieve the desired inline behavior.

```cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(int))]
public class IntExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public IntExtension(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

Then it's as simple as:

```xaml
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{local:Int 5}">
```